# Optimal database lookup and update in pandas/python

Tags: python, sql, pandas, cursor, pyodbc

theoretical database/coding query here - Python / Pandas dataframe related. I'm dealing with up to 50k rows in a table so optimal solutions seem... erm, optimal. And I'm no coding expert either, so, bear with me.

I have a table with unique child code/country pair rows, some with matching parent codes.Eg:

```
Index | Parent | Child | Country | NewValue
0     |  A     |  A-1  |  X      | Null
1     |  A     |  A-1  |  Y      | Null 
2     |  A     |  A-2  |  X      | Null
3     |  B     |  B-1  |  X      | Null
4     |  B     |  B-2  |  Y      | Null
```

I need to update every Parent / Country pair with a calculated unique value (NewValue). What's the best approach to finding and updating each pair over every row?

So far I'm generating a seperate list of unique Parent / Country pairs (to avoid calculating NewValue for every row needlessly; I just itterate through this list generating NewValue for each pair), eg:

```
Parent | Country
A      |  X
A      |  Y
B      |  X
B      |  Y
```

Now, is it better to simply do a lookup in the first table for every given parent/country match, get the row index for any matching rows, and then update via the row index?

Or, generate the second table in a way that includes any relevant indexes to start with, and use these to update the first table? Eg:

```
Parent | Country | Index(s)
A      | X       | 0,2
A      | Y       | 1
B      | X       | 3
B      | Y       | 4
```

If 2, how? Because I'm using df.unique() to generate the second table, I only get one index per pair, not any mathing indexes (and I'm not sure how they'd show up if I did). And I'm not sure if either way is particularly good, but it's the best I've come up with in a day :o)

Thanks,

Christopher / pepsi_max2k

Comment: sounds like you need to do a groupby

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to look at the [merge](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) function.

What you have to do in your case is

```
df_children.merge(df_parent, on=["Parent","Country"])
```

where df_children is your table with [Index | Parent | Child | Country] columns and df_parent has [Parent | Country | NewValue]